# bind positive and negative x-axis ggplot lines into one domain

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, line

I have two line graphs, their y-axis is the same as in probability, but the x-axis is different, one is in positive domain and another is in negative. But I want to overlap the two lines in one domain and to visually compare the slopes. How can I achieve that in `ggplot`?

df1

```
 prob           gain
0.09566978      0.010
0.18838910      6.538
0.31826666      13.066
0.47170068      19.594
0.62754900      26.122
0.76485831      32.650
```

df2

```
 prob            loss
0.04004953      -32.650
0.10689695      -26.122
0.22896403      -19.594
0.40107903      -13.066
0.59289582      -6.538
0.76498002      -0.010
```

current code

```
library(ggplot2)
all <- ggplot() + 
    geom_line(data = df1, aes(x = gain, y = 
    prob), color = "red") + ylim(c(0,1)) +
    geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = loss, y = 
    prob), color = "blue") + ylim(c(0,1))
```

[image]

I want to use the same axis (positive) for the two lines.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do `x = -loss` or `x=abs(loss)` in `aes` depending on what is meaningful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution where on `loss` data we use `abs()` and `rev()` (you need both).

```
# Using OPs data
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
    geom_line(data = df1, 
              aes(gain, prob), 
              color = "red") + 
    geom_line(data = df2, 
              aes(rev(abs(loss)), prob), 
              color = "blue") +
    labs(x = NULL) +
    ylim(c(0,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question! That's what I wanted, seems I did poor job on the description.

Comment: one follow-up question. How can I put legend on `ggplot` if they are from different dataframes? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what you really mean. If you want to flip the curve, do what @Sébastien Rochette suggested. If you want to shift to shift the curve maybe you want to do

```
df2$loss <- df2$loss + (df1$gain[1] - df2$loss[1])
```

Like I said - not sure, if that's what you want. It's definitely in the data and not in the plot.